# How to get only the document libraries from a sharePoint site using SharePoint Client Object Model?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

Usually when we need to get all the document libraries from a SharePoint site, we can follow the given code snippet:-

```
SPListCollection lstCol = oSite.OpenWeb().GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
```

But how to get the same result using SharePoint Client Object Model?
Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi u just get all list from site and just check it's BaseType like this

```
using (ClientContext clientcontext= new ClientContext("http://your server"))
{

    //Load Libraries from SharePoint
    clientcontext.Load(clientcontext.Web.Lists);
    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (List list in clientcontext.Web.Lists)
    {
       try
       {
            if (list.BaseType.ToString() == "DocumentLibrary")
             {
                 // here u get all document library
             }
       }
       catch()
       {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is better as it only pulls back the document libraries rather than all the lists which you then have to check in a loop.

```
 var Libraries = clientContext.LoadQuery(clientContext.Web.Lists.Where(l => l.BaseTemplate == 101));
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Also note that I've used the BaseTemplate property which has more granularity than BaseType.  You can get ListTemplate enumeration values which map to the CSOM BaseTemplate property from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype.aspx).

Comment: Goes this work in JavaScript?

Comment: @Batman, not sure if there is a JavaScript equivalent; I doubt it can do the LINQ / IQueryable stuff.